# I am confused of managing bit locker?

Tags: bitlocker

I am using windows 10 pro which contains two partitions, partition C and Partition E. I currently removed bit locker of my partition E not C, i want to re lock it, how i can re lock my partition?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on drive E, click "Turn on Bitlocker", follow the instruction on screen until done.